# How can i send mail and sms with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, email, sms

i added call function with swift 3 like that:

```
@IBAction func call_click(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt://" + phone_number!)!
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
}
```

This code calling and back to app normally. i want to add mail and sms too.
How can i do that?

Comment: Use `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SMS use this URL schema:

```
sms:1-408-555-1212
```

as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html

For email use `mailto:`

```
mailto:foo@example.com?cc=bar@example.com&subject=Greetings%20from%20Cupertino!&body=Wish%20you%20were%20here!
```

as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html

Hope this helped.

Comment: While this works, it's not the best solution for the user. See the comment below the question by Paulw11.

Comment: I know. Yet, the op has not detailed the use case. Maybe he reads URLs dynamically and requires to use the build-in viewers and capabilities. If he merely wants to send Email, then using the URL to pop up the mail program is not very flexible, indeed.